# SharePoint 2010 : Visual Webpart - Multiple User Control

Tags: web-part, visual-studio, user-controls, visual-web-part

SharePoint 2010: Visual Studio 2010

I have requirement : i have one web part and using custom web part property i load 4 different user control.

Solution 1 : I created web part and using custom web part property I load the different user control.[This deploys successfully and works as expected ]

Solution 2 : Can I use Visual web part for the same ?
i tried creating the visual web part and added 3 user control (+ 1 default user control by visual web part).After deploying , 14 hive contained only the default user control not the other 3 user control.

Question : Can i achieve the same using visual web part .If Not , any justification?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Web part basically does the same as solution 1, as it loads a user control in CreateChildControls (the exception is a Sandboxed visual web part, where the codebehind for the usercontrol inherits from webpart).

Since user controls doesnt show up in CONTROLTEMPLATES: did you remember to set the added user controls as DeploymentType: TemplateFile?

[image]

Comment: can u explain your statement "did you remember to set the added user controls as DeploymentType: TemplateFile?" in more detail

Comment: sure. i added a screenshot of the property in question